# Imaging: Replaces values by 0 over specific threshold

Tags: python, image, nifti

I have data of type float64 which has the size (57, 66, 40). I want to replace all values smaller than 0.9 by 0.

I tried the easiest way without a loop:

```
img = nib.load('/home/anja/aw.nii')

data = img.get_fdata()

threshold_data = data[data<0.9] == 0
```

But then I get threshold_data as type bool with size of (55318,). So I lost the dimensions of my image. 
Can someone help me how to do this, that I still have my image of dimension (57, 66, 40) and just replace values <0.9 in there by 0.

Comment: What kind of thing is `data`? Pandas dataframe? Numpy array? Pillow image?

Comment: Your code does not match your objective, you got `<` and `>` mixed up

Comment: oh silly error. yes of course

Comment: I loaded as an nifti

Comment: Why do you use `== 0`? Did you mean `= 0`?

Comment: I want to set those values <0.9 to 0. If I set = 0 than I get a int of size 1 with value 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to nipy docs, the `get_fdata()` method returns a NumPy array, so the easiest method is just:

```py
img = nib.load('/home/anja/aw.nii')

data = img.get_fdata()

data[data<0.9] = 0

print(data.shape)
```

Comment: this returns an integer of size 1 set to 0. I want to have the NumPy array of size (57, 66, 40) which has zeros where before values smaller 0.9 were..

Comment: Have you printed the `data.shape` after  `data[data<0.9] = 0`? Its not about what returns but what make in the data variable itself